# How to install dlux into ODL Magnesium

Tags: opendaylight

I was trying to install DLUX (https://github.com/opendaylight/dlux) into ODL Magnesium however instructions in the GitHub page are outdated.

I also tried this (which turns out ok):

```
feature:repo-add mvn:org.opendaylight.dlux/odl-dlux-core/0.9.2/xml/features
```

And then this (nok):

```
feature:install odl-dlux-core
```

After 1 hour processing both memory consumption and cpu utilization go as high as it can get and then everything freezes.

Does anybody know the corret step-by-step to install DLUX into ODL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short, the last ODL version supporting dlux core and dlux apps was Oxygen. We welcome any contribution to migrate dlux to Magnesium or any other recent version.